# carburetor failure in yamaha dt lanza

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, yamaha

I have a problem with DT Lanza carburetor and the mechanic said I need to replace all the parts in carburetor. Can I get DT 200r carburetor on the DT Lanza 230, because it is hard to find it's spare parts in carburetor in my country. How would the performance be if I get the DT 200r carburetor on the DT Lanza?

Comment: What is the year of your motorcycle?  What country are you in?  To clarify, you have a DT 230 and you are asking if you can replace it with a DT 200 carburetor?  Any questions you can put into your question will help to clarify your post.

Answer (score 6):

**The DT 230 Carburetor will fit on some DT200's**

The 1999 model of your bike uses the ***Mikuni  TM30x1 Flat Slide Carburetor***

Older models use a different carburetor model.  The slide is round.

Here is an image of the flat slide carburetor.

[image]

Here is an image of the round slide carburetor

[image]

Both of these carburetors are readily available on ebay and [Google shop](https://www.google.com/search?q=TM30x1&oq=TM30x1&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=mikuni%20carburetor%20TM30x1&tbm=shop&spd=18017864666151687805).